# How can I improve performance of a 'LIKE'-linked LEFT JOIN (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I'm having some problems with performance of a join that uses LIKE to make the join. An example setup is described below.  Table1 grows over the period of the day up to a few thousand rows.  Table2 is a lookup table and is constant in size with just a few dozen entries. As more data is added to Table1, the query performance worsens massively to a point where it becomes effectively unusable.

I have indexes on `Table1.Entity` and `Table2.EntityJoin`

I've build the tables this way, with wildcarded `EntityJoin` values so the front end can define filters that map similar entity names to a particular group.  It appeared to me it would be more efficient from a user's point of view to be able to use wildcards rather than have to define every single entity name from Table1 in Table2 (note, this structure is a massively simplified view for sake of example).

I've read through a few similar posts regarding join performance, but didn't see any that use LIKE in the way I'm trying to use it.

Table1:

```
------------------------
Entity
------------------------
AnEntity1
AnEntity2
OtherEntity1
Other3Entity
Other12Entity
MoreEntities2
EvenMore3Entities5
------------------------
```

Table2:

```
---------------------------------
EntityJoin     | JoinName
---------------------------------
An%            | SomeVal
Other%         | SomeVal
More%          | SomeOtherVal
---------------------------------
```

Query

```
select 
    *
from
    Table1 T1
    left join Table2 T2
        on T1.Entity like T2.EntityJoin;
```

Comment: A few thousands rows per day? That's about 2-3 million rows per year, which is nothing for the Oracle DB. Even if you want to do something like that, you should look at table partitioning instead of creating a separate table. As to the performance - most probably you do not have proper indexes on `Table1`. Anyway, it's hard to tell untill you show us the queries you run against `Table1` which you consider to be slow.

Comment: Can you show us the explain plan, and any index definitions.

Comment: you cannot avoid the first full scan but you can somehow "crop" execution time if you get the EntityJoin filters sorted by length as the more restrictive would run first then

Comment: I'm new to `explain plan`.  Which columns from the plan table are useful for sharing here?

Comment: Store EntityJoin low and high values, like `Anaaaaaaa` and `Anzzzzzzzz` instead. Then join `on  T1.Entity between T2.EntityJoinlow and T2.EntityJoinhigh`.

Comment: @Bob you can use parallel hint in your scenario. depends on the cpu you have.

Answer (score 0):

Best what you can expect with your query is 
Full Table Scan on table 1
and a nested loop to table 2.

This is because you have to check every entry in t1 if it matches to any entry in t2.

T2 like

```
---------------------------------
EntityJoin     | JoinName
---------------------------------
An%            | SomeVal
A%             | SomeVal
AnE%           | SomeOtherVal
---------------------------------
```

would be possible and entries:

```
AnEntity1
AnEntity2
```

would triple.

So you have to think about what can be done to be more selective.